# redirect to other html file with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to redirect from a.html to b.html with a parameter for example array c[],i used something like `location.href = "b.html";` but when i write something like `console.log(c[0].name);` in my .js i got nothing after the redirection to b.html!
thanks in advance for your help :)

```js
$(".btn").click(function(){
    location.href = "b.html"; 
    //.. push of some elemts to the array elements
    // .. try to show elements in b.html with console.log() for example
});
```

Comment: Once you've redirected, the JS after that won't be executed.

Comment: so how could i receive my array in the new html file ? :)

Comment: a.html and b.html cannot interact via JS. It needs to be done either server side, or maybe by passing query parameters to b.html (but it depends on what you want to do. Maybe post an example less abstract).

Comment: The browser clears JS state between pages. You need to store the data somewhere, either in localStorage, sessionStorage, the querystring, a cookie or in a database.

Comment: If you array is plain objects like string & numbers etc, you could convert to JSON, and URIEncode it into a query parameter.  eg. "b.html?params=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(prams)), and then from b.js do the reverse..  Or alternatively store in a cookie / localstorage etc.

Comment: Another alternative is to use Ajax loading of your HTML pages..

Comment: in a.html i want to receive an array of students with some attributes like name,age... and then i want to send it to b.html and show it in a table.

Answer (score 0):

As commented before, once you are redirected, you are literally on a new page. So everything you had before is unloaded. ( And your script which is supposed to execute after setting the location.href is stopped )

There are several ways to handle data into the next page, but by far the most easiest one would be to use query-parameter in your URI. Check that out:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

You are limited by the size of data, the data is somehow visible, and it could be easily hacked, though - but it seems you are quite at the start of something anyway.(?)